# Apache httpd: Conditionally setting response header based on file type. Which file do I need to add “X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff” to?

Tags: javascript, apache, http-headers, httpresponse, mime-types

I am trying to add "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" header to all HTTP responses.

I added the below code to one of the Apache configuration files that gets loaded from main config file (httpd.conf), but I still don't see the header while inspecting the URL.

What am I missing here?

Code-

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|m?js)$">
       Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say, all files, but there is a filematch directive. Remove that for all files or please give a hint for a URL that doesnt match. The filematch is for .css$ for example.

Comment: I want this header to be applied for .css and .js files only. Hence I have used the filematch directive.

Comment: Ok. I asume, mod_headers is enabled. Did you try it without Filesmatch? Did it work for „all“ files? The regex could be \.(css|js)$. I‘m not sure, what m?js should be.

Comment: I read here https://github.com/webhintio/hint/blob/6ae8df828c582b8eb40d03342ec8faf26ef8debf/docs/user-guide/rules/x-content-type-options.md, that script files go by extension .js or .mjs and .css, hence the regex. Not tried without Filesmatch yet, will check and update on that.

Comment: Also where should I put his code? Does this need to go in httpd.conf file or any of the .conf file works. 
And do I need to use "LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so"? If yes, then where?

Comment: Do you use a linux distribution? Like debian? Then I would say, use the given mechanism/scripts to add a module (See a2enmod). Your code should be added to a virtualhost or location directive. If you dont use distro version, then grep for LoadModule etc. and add it there. Otherwise you can put it wherever you want.

Comment: I guess the problem may be with mod_headers. Can you let me know how do we enable mod_headers?

Comment: of course - I need some more informations. The LoadModule directive is important. The location of the *.so file to. The problem is - I don't know, which distribution you're using, that would help, giving the answer you need. Can you make a grep -r 'LoadModule' in the directory where the httpd.conf is? Then look for the output. Which file (if not httpd.conf) contains the other LoadModule directives (I'm sure, there are more then zero by default).

Comment: We use CentOS. Also after adding the LoadModule to one of the configuration files, I can see the header now getting added in all responses, but that is happening without the filesmatch directive. If I use the filesmatch directive to limit it to only javascript and css files, it does not work.